# Subquery returns more than 1 row - How to get the last update date of a row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table with device ID and the date and time of the last update, I'm trying to make a MySQL query to get the last seen update of each device on the table, but when I execute my query, I'm getting the following error:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Below is the query that I'm using on my PHP code.

```
SELECT log_device_dt_lastupdate FROM tb_log_device 
WHERE device_id=(SELECT DISTINCT(device_id) 
FROM tb_log_device) ORDER BY log_device_dt_lastupdate 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

If I use `GROUP_CONCAT` I just get the information from one device.

I don't want to use two queries to get this info from the table, is it possible to have it? Maybe by making a `JOIN`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `group by` and `max()` `aggregation`

```
SELECT deviceid,max(log_device_dt_lastupdate) 
FROM tb_log_device 
group by deviceid
```

Comment: Works perfect, but I can't get the row log_device_dt_lastupdate, only the device_id show in the php array, I tried SELECT deviceid, log_device_dt_lastupdate, max(log_device_dt_lastupdate) but not work too. I need the last update time to compare with actual timedate.

Answer (score 0):

Use where_in

```
SELECT log_device_dt_lastupdate FROM tb_log_device 
WHERE device_id IN 
(SELECT device_id 
FROM tb_log_device 
ORDER BY log_device_dt_lastupdate DESC)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the query are returning a lot of old timestamps.